# Print more than one label on a sheet in MyLabel Designer Deluxe

Tags: printing, label-printer

I have a whole sheet of labels, and MyLabel Designer (not the printer driver) says it can handle repeating / tiling the label across a sheet.  But it doesn't.  Print preview even shows a bunch of empty labels in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after poking around, I found that this program prints one label per "record."  You need to make a record (it can be nonsense) for each label you want to print.